# Sort a list of dictionary with order of specific key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a `list` of `dict` like this:

```
data = [{"uid": "a1", "name": "b1"}, 
        {"uid": "a3", "name": "b3"}, 
        {"uid": "a4", "name": "b4"},
        {"uid": "a5", "name": "b5"}]
```

Now I want to sort that `list` with the order of the `uid` field like this:

```
uid_order = ['a1', 'a5', 'a3', 'a4']
```

Which means the output should be:

```
[{"uid": "a1", "name": "b1"}, 
 {"uid": "a5", "name": "b5"},
 {"uid": "a3", "name": "b3"},
 {"uid": "a4", "name": "b4"}]
```

Of course, I can create a new empty `list` then use 2 `for` loops to check and add every element, but is there any elegant way (or better complexity) to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: Nope, that answer only work if `uid_order` is already in decending/ascending order

Comment: I see. My bad I saw what I expected to see when reading the question, should have seen the specific order you requested. Would updating the heading to "Sort a list of dictionaries on key in non-standard order" be an improvement maybe? It will be easier for other to find if they have the same question I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O(n) solution:

```
>>> [*map({d['uid']: d for d in data}.get, uid_order)]
[{'uid': 'a1', 'name': 'b1'},
 {'uid': 'a5', 'name': 'b5'},
 {'uid': 'a3', 'name': 'b3'},
 {'uid': 'a4', 'name': 'b4'}]
```

Comment: `list(...)` is arguably cleaner than `[*...]`, but this is very neat

Comment: @MadPhysicist I used to think so, too, but I'm getting used to `[*...]` and I like it for the consistency with `[2, 3, 5]` and `[<list comp>]`. Maybe one day everyone is going to use it, except of course those people who today still write `set([...])` insted of `{...}` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can sort a list in place with it's [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method if you want to avoid making a new list. This will use Timsort, which has `O(n log n)` complexity, much better than your suggested `O(n^2)` implementation:

```
uid_order = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(uid_order)}
data.sort(key=uid_order.get)
```

To speed up lookup into `uid_order`, I invert it into a dictionary (invert because a list maps index to item, while you want item to index). Instead of an `O(n)` lookup at each evaluation of the key, you have an `O(1)` lookup now.

An alternative way to make the dictionary using only function calls:

```
uid_order = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(uid_order)))
```

See also: [Python Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto)

Answer (score 2):

With the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted)-function you can specify a key that the function should sort after. You want to access the value of the `"uid"` key for each dictionary and that value's index in `uid_order` determines that dictionary's index in the sorted list:

```py
sorted(data, key = lambda x: uid_order.index(x["uid"]))
```

What this code means is, each element of the list gets passed to the `lambda`-function. The resulting value is used as key to sort after.

Comment: Very nice, I love the one line code but unfortunately I'm looking for better performance so I have to accept @Mad Physicist solution, sorry about that :D